# How to make rest of the columns the same height of the first one in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have 3 columns in a web dialog, the first one is a form, the second one is a list of images, and the last one is a list of cards.

[image]

How can I make the image list and the card list the same height as the left most form?

```
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        // List of Form Fields

                SizedBox(width: 30),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 400,
                    width: 50,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: ImageList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 300,
                          width: 50,
                          child: Image.network(ImageList[index].image_path),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 30),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 400,
                    width: 50,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: QuestionList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children:[
                                Text(QuestionList[index].question),
                                Text(QuestionList[index].answer),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

I tried to set height of both lists to infinity or mediaQuery neither works.

Comment: Take a look at package Boxy in the pub.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your columns with expanded and remove the heigh from the containers to make the expanded take the advantages.

Comment: I did as shown in my code to wrap in Expanded, but removing the height of the containers give rendering error.